# SoapUI properties substitution in REST request body

Tags: rest, soapui

I want to substitute SoapUI properties in the REST request body content. I'm using a JMS endpoint.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<foopartner xmlns="http://www.foo.com/foopartner">
    <partnerKey>${#TestCase#partnerKey}</partnerKey>
</foopartner>
```

Using `${#TestCase#partnerKey}` in a SOAP request substitution works fine. For REST requests it passes the xml as is without substitution.

How can I achieve a substitution? I'm using SoapUI version 4.6.2. Is it a bug?

Comment: I use SoapUI 4.5.1 to test REST web-services and everything works fine. The only difference is that I use JSON but not XML format.

Comment: @olyv I've tried 4.6 and 4.6.2. Maybe it's a regression. You use a json request body with properties being substituted ($-substitution)? I'll give 4.5.1 a try.

Comment: YEs, I use it like this ${#TestSuite#nameOfNeededProperty}

Comment: If I send the request to a **HTTP** endpoint property substitution **works** fine. In my case I have a **JMS** endpoint and in this case no property substitution takes place. (Tried SoapUI 4.5.1, 4.6.2 and 4.6.3)

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/p/soapui/bugs/  :)

Comment: It really seems to be a bug which I found (and confirmed) here: http://forum.soapui.org/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=15427

Comment: Neither sourceforge.net/p/soapui/bugs nor bugs in forum.soapui.org seem to be taken actively into consideration by the soapui developers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a workaround. I leave the request body empty and add the content a and attachment and set the type to `text/xml`. Properties in the attachment are being expanded/substituted and the attachment is sent as an ordinary request body.

You can use relative paths for the attachment filename using `${projectDir}/path/to/file.xml`.